How can I demonstrate something about $\mathbb{Z}^n$ working on $\mathbb{Q}^n$?
I'm working on an exercise and I don't know how to resolve it.   It says: "Consider $\mathbb{Z}^n$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the product of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ for itself $n$ times and consider $\phi$ an endomorphism on $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Demonstrate that $\phi$ is injective iff $\space$ $\mathbb{Z}^n/Im(\phi)$ is a finite group."  It also suggests to consider the endomorphism $\phi_\mathbb{Q}$ on $\mathbb{Q}^n$ associated at $\phi$.   At the moment I have demonstrated that my endomorphism $\phi$ is univocally determinated by what it does on the vectors $ e_i $, the standard "basis", with $a_i := \phi(e_i) $; I also demonstrated that $\phi$ is injective iff the vectors $a_i$ are linearly independent on $\mathbb{Z}^n$ iff the vectors $a_i$ are linearly independent on $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and so if I consider them in $\mathbb{Q}^n$, seen as a vector space, they are a basis.  Actually I don't know if I'm using the right approach, because I don't know what I can deduce from that. How can I use this information in order to say something about $\mathbb{Z}^n/Im(\phi)$?

Hint: A group is of finite order if and only if it is finitely generated and all its elements are of finite order. Use a characterization of injective endomorphisms on finite dimensional vector spaces to reach the conclusion.

Thanks for the answer, using your hint I came out with that: ${a_1, ..., a_n}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}^n$, so I can express the vectors of the standard basis ${e_i}$ as linear combinations with coefficents in $\mathbb{Q}$ of $a_i$,$\space$ so, multypling accurately,$\space \forall i \space \exists z_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $z_ie_i \in \langle a_i, ..., a_n \rangle _\mathbb{Z}$. Now ${e_i}$ generates $\mathbb{Z}^n$, so their equivalence classes generate $\mathbb{Z}^n/Im(\phi)$ and they all have finite order, cause $Im(\phi)=\langle a_i, ..., a_n \rangle _\mathbb{Z}$. Is it ok?

Instead, if ${a_1,...,a_n}$ are not linearly independent in $\mathbb{Z}^n$, they are not linearly independent in $\mathbb{Q}^n$, so at least one of the $e_i$ cannot be generated by linear combination of the $a_i$ in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and so $\forall z \in \mathbb{Z}, ze_i∉⟨a1,...,an⟩_\mathbb{Z}$, so I have an element of $\mathbb{Z}^n/Im(\phi)$ of infinite order and that means that $\mathbb{Z}^n/Im(\phi)$ isn't a finite group. And in this way I should have demonstrated the iff. There was a typo in the previous comment, now it should be all correct @Boxonix
